# Dynamic Form with dependent Selects in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to create a form in which the fields are dynamically generated from the database api. The problem is that I have cases where I will have two selection fields, and one depends on the other.

For example:
Selection A - Manufacturer,
Selection B - Models

The Models that should be shown in selection B must only be the models of the manufacturer choosen in selection A.

As the form is made dynamically I don't have fixed states where I can check the value of selection A.

Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: and what you do so far?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put an onChange handle on the Selection A (Manufacturer) in order to get the Selection B (Models) mounted based on the selected manufacturer.

Maybe you can fetch the models just after Selection A had a value selected.

Or, if you got all the models in the same moment when the manufacturers are fetched, when manufacturer will be selected you could filter models using it as reference.

Comment: Hi Izac, thanks for your help, but if I understand your suggestions this not resolve, because like I mention before the component is dynamic genereted, so I can't put a handle in a specific selection A, in fact the component is the same for selection a and b.

Answer (score 0):

I found the aswer and is very simple on my case, I'm using react-hook-form, so I only need use the watch function to see the valeu of
selection A, passing the name id of the component.